# Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 (arm64) refusing SSH connection

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I need to install ROS on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. According to instructions, this is better to do from an Ubuntu-mate distro following standard ARM instructions

(http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Melodic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi)

I already flashed the SD card with the Ubuntu image and now I'm trying to access my Raspberry Pi over SSH (Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 arm64) but it keeps refusing the connection even when I already added a ssh file on the root directory. This is what it's within the partition

```
G:\
¦   README
¦   bootcode.bin
¦   cmdline.txt
¦   config.txt
¦   fixup.dat
¦   fixup4.dat
¦   fixup4cd.dat
¦   fixup4db.dat
¦   fixup4x.dat
¦   fixup_cd.dat
¦   fixup_db.dat
¦   fixup_x.dat
¦   start.elf
¦   start4.elf
¦   start4cd.elf
¦   start4db.elf
¦   start4x.elf
¦   start_cd.elf
¦   start_db.elf
¦   start_x.elf
¦   bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
¦   bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
¦   bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
¦   bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
¦   bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
¦   bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb
¦   bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
¦   bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
¦   bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb
¦   boot.scr
¦   initrd.img
¦   overlay_map.dtb
¦   syscfg.txt
¦   uboot_rpi_3.bin
¦   uboot_rpi_4.bin
¦   usercfg.txt
¦   vmlinuz
¦   ssh
¦   
+---overlays
        adau7002-simple.dtbo
        act-led.dtbo
        adafruit18.dtbo
        adau1977-adc.dtbo
        akkordion-iqdacplus.dtbo
        ads1015.dtbo
        ads1115.dtbo
        ads7846.dtbo
        adv7282m.dtbo
        adv728x-m.dtbo
        audioinjector-addons.dtbo
        anyspi.dtbo
        allo-boss-dac-pcm512x-audio.dtbo
        allo-digione.dtbo
        allo-katana-dac-audio.dtbo
        allo-piano-dac-pcm512x-audio.dtbo
        allo-piano-dac-plus-pcm512x-audio.dtbo
        apds9960.dtbo
        applepi-dac.dtbo
        at86rf233.dtbo
        dionaudio-loco-v2.dtbo
        audremap.dtbo
        audioinjector-isolated-soundcard.dtbo
        audioinjector-ultra.dtbo
        audioinjector-wm8731-audio.dtbo
        audiosense-pi.dtbo
        balena-fin.dtbo
        cma.dtbo
        dht11.dtbo
        dionaudio-loco.dtbo
        disable-bt.dtbo
        disable-wifi.dtbo
        dpi18.dtbo
        dpi24.dtbo
        draws.dtbo
        dwc-otg.dtbo
        dwc2.dtbo
        enc28j60-spi2.dtbo
        enc28j60.dtbo
        exc3000.dtbo
        fe-pi-audio.dtbo
        goodix.dtbo
        googlevoicehat-soundcard.dtbo
        gpio-fan.dtbo
        gpio-ir-tx.dtbo
        gpio-ir.dtbo
        gpio-key.dtbo
        gpio-no-bank0-irq.dtbo
        gpio-no-irq.dtbo
        gpio-poweroff.dtbo
        gpio-shutdown.dtbo
        hd44780-lcd.dtbo
        hdmi-backlight-hwhack-gpio.dtbo
        hifiberry-amp.dtbo
        hifiberry-dac.dtbo
        hifiberry-dacplus.dtbo
        hifiberry-dacplusadc.dtbo
        hifiberry-dacplusadcpro.dtbo
        hifiberry-dacplusdsp.dtbo
        hifiberry-dacplushd.dtbo
        hifiberry-digi-pro.dtbo
        hifiberry-digi.dtbo
        highperi.dtbo
        hy28a.dtbo
        hy28b-2017.dtbo
        hy28b.dtbo
        i-sabre-q2m.dtbo
        i2c-bcm2708.dtbo
        i2c-gpio.dtbo
        i2c-mux.dtbo
        i2c-pwm-pca9685a.dtbo
        i2c-rtc-gpio.dtbo
        i2c-rtc.dtbo
        i2c-sensor.dtbo
        i2c0.dtbo
        i2c1.dtbo
        i2c3.dtbo
        i2c4.dtbo
        i2c5.dtbo
        i2c6.dtbo
        i2s-gpio28-31.dtbo
        ilitek251x.dtbo
        imx219.dtbo
        imx290.dtbo
        imx477.dtbo
        iqaudio-codec.dtbo
        iqaudio-dac.dtbo
        iqaudio-dacplus.dtbo
        iqaudio-digi-wm8804-audio.dtbo
        irs1125.dtbo
        jedec-spi-nor.dtbo
        justboom-both.dtbo
        justboom-dac.dtbo
        justboom-digi.dtbo
        ltc294x.dtbo
        max98357a.dtbo
        maxtherm.dtbo
        mbed-dac.dtbo
        mcp23017.dtbo
        mcp23s17.dtbo
        mcp2515-can0.dtbo
        mcp2515-can1.dtbo
        mcp3008.dtbo
        mcp3202.dtbo
        mcp342x.dtbo
        media-center.dtbo
        merus-amp.dtbo
        midi-uart0.dtbo
        midi-uart1.dtbo
        miniuart-bt.dtbo
        mmc.dtbo
        mpu6050.dtbo
        mz61581.dtbo
        ov5647.dtbo
        ov7251.dtbo
        ov9281.dtbo
        overlay_map.dtb
        papirus.dtbo
        pca953x.dtbo
        pibell.dtbo
        pifacedigital.dtbo
        piglow.dtbo
        piscreen.dtbo
        piscreen2r.dtbo
        pisound.dtbo
        pitft22.dtbo
        pitft28-capacitive.dtbo
        pitft28-resistive.dtbo
        pitft35-resistive.dtbo
        pps-gpio.dtbo
        pwm-2chan.dtbo
        pwm-ir-tx.dtbo
        pwm.dtbo
        qca7000.dtbo
        rotary-encoder.dtbo
        rpi-backlight.dtbo
        rpi-cirrus-wm5102.dtbo
        rpi-dac.dtbo
        rpi-display.dtbo
        rpi-ft5406.dtbo
        rpi-poe.dtbo
        rpi-proto.dtbo
        rpi-sense.dtbo
        rpi-tv.dtbo
        rpivid-v4l2.dtbo
        rra-digidac1-wm8741-audio.dtbo
        sainsmart18.dtbo
        sc16is750-i2c.dtbo
        sc16is752-i2c.dtbo
        sc16is752-spi0.dtbo
        sc16is752-spi1.dtbo
        sdhost.dtbo
        sdio.dtbo
        sdtweak.dtbo
        sh1106-spi.dtbo
        smi-dev.dtbo
        smi-nand.dtbo
        smi.dtbo
        spi-gpio35-39.dtbo
        spi-gpio40-45.dtbo
        spi-rtc.dtbo
        spi0-1cs.dtbo
        spi0-2cs.dtbo
        spi0-cs.dtbo
        spi0-hw-cs.dtbo
        spi1-1cs.dtbo
        spi1-2cs.dtbo
        spi1-3cs.dtbo
        spi2-1cs.dtbo
        spi2-2cs.dtbo
        spi2-3cs.dtbo
        spi3-1cs.dtbo
        spi3-2cs.dtbo
        spi4-1cs.dtbo
        spi4-2cs.dtbo
        spi5-1cs.dtbo
        spi5-2cs.dtbo
        spi6-1cs.dtbo
        spi6-2cs.dtbo
        ssd1306-spi.dtbo
        ssd1306.dtbo
        ssd1351-spi.dtbo
        superaudioboard.dtbo
        sx150x.dtbo
        tc358743-audio.dtbo
        tc358743.dtbo
        tinylcd35.dtbo
        tpm-slb9670.dtbo
        uart0.dtbo
        uart1.dtbo
        uart2.dtbo
        uart3.dtbo
        uart4.dtbo
        uart5.dtbo
        udrc.dtbo
        upstream-pi4.dtbo
        upstream.dtbo
        vc4-fkms-v3d.dtbo
        vc4-kms-kippah-7inch.dtbo
        vc4-kms-v3d-pi4.dtbo
        vc4-kms-v3d.dtbo
        vga666.dtbo
        w1-gpio-pullup.dtbo
        w1-gpio.dtbo
        w5500.dtbo
        wittypi.dtbo
```

I can see my device connected to the router and there is an IP address assigned to it but when I try the SSH the connection is refused.

Any clues on this?

Comment: Did you install an SSH server? A stock install of Ubuntu Desktop (incuding flavors like MATE) does not typically include an SSH server. It's a trivial step (`sudo apt install openssh-server`) but an essential step.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @user535733 the problem is that we have a headless install and I need to find a way to access the pi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  You are right. Let me add more details. @user535733